# Vectorized lambda function with element-eise condition

Tags: python-3.x, lambda, conditional-statements, vectorization

I would like to have a  conditional `lambda` function, where the condition-checking is applied elemt-by-elemnent. I have the following code:

```
p = np.arange(0,1,0.01)
Kl = lambda p: p + 1 if p>0.5 else p-1
K = Kl(p)
```

which produces the error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous.
Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Why is it not possible to use lambda functions in this way? Can someone suggest the proper way to acheive this? Thanks.

Comment: You're comparing an array to a float. `[0,0.01,0.02,...,0.99] > 0.5` can't be resolved.

Comment: Try `list(map(Kl, p))`

Comment: `list(map(Kl, p))` indeed solved it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `np.where()`

```
In [5]: import numpy as np

In [6]: p = np.arange(0, 1, 0.1)

In [7]: l = lambda x: np.where(x>0.5, x+1, x-1)

In [8]: l(p)
Out[8]: array([-1. , -0.9, -0.8, -0.7, -0.6, -0.5,  1.6,  1.7,  1.8,  1.9])
```

---

#### Timings

Using vectorized expressions is faster than using listy ones, especially if the dimensions of the arrays involved are large. In the following the `np.where(…)` is ~70 times faster than `list(map(…))` for a 1 million items, while the advantage is much less for 100 items...

```
In [14]: p = np.arange(0, 1, 0.000001)

In [15]: K0 = lambda p: np.where(p>0.5, p+1, p-1)

In [16]: K1 = lambda p: p + 1 if p>0.5 else p-1

In [17]: %timeit _ = K0(p)
100 loops, best of 3: 8.1 ms per loop

In [18]: %timeit _ = list(map(K1, p))
1 loop, best of 3: 557 ms per loop

In [19]: p = np.arange(0, 1, 0.01)

In [20]: %timeit _ = K0(p)
The slowest run took 9.97 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 6.99 µs per loop

In [21]: %timeit _ = list(map(K1, p))
10000 loops, best of 3: 58.5 µs per loop
```